# Getting Mysql_Close Error

Tags: php, mysql, curl, database-connection, mysql-error-1064

I am receiving a mysql_close() error for the bellow code, although as I see it the syntax is correct. It opens fine, the variable is correct. Any suggestions? Code is live here (http://obsidianpunch.com/Summer) error is Warning: mysql_close(): 5 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/content/53/7382753/html/Summer/wootsummer.php on line 97

line 97 is

```
mysql_close($con);
```

Here is wootsummer.php

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit (0);

$urls=explode("\n", $_POST['url']);
//$proxies=explode("\n", $_POST['proxy']);

$target=$_POST['target'];

$allurls=count($urls);
//$allproxies=count($proxies);

//use the new tool box
require "ToolBoxA4.php";


for ( $counter = 0; $counter < $allurls; $counter++) {
//for ( $count = 0; $count <= $allproxies; $count++) {


 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$urls[$counter]);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'GET');
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
 curl_exec ($ch); 
 $curl_scraped_page=curl_exec($ch); 


//call the new function parseA1
$arrOut = parseA1 ($curl_scraped_page);


$curl_scraped_page=strtolower($curl_scraped_page);
$haystack=$curl_scraped_page;
if (strlen(strstr($haystack,$target))>0) {



$FileName = abs(rand(0,100000));
$FileHandle = fopen($FileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($FileHandle, $curl_scraped_page);


$hostname="*******";
$username="hatrick";
$password="*******";
$dbname="hatrick";
$usertable="happyturtle";

$con=mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die ("<html><script language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script></html>");
mysql_select_db($dbname ,$con);
if (!$con)
   {
   die(mysql_error());
   }
 mysql_close($con);

$right = explode(",", $arrOut[0]);
$top = explode(",", $arrOut[1]);

for ( $countforme = 0; $countforme < 6; $countforme++) {
//$topnow=$top[$countforme];
//echo '$topnow';

$query = "INSERT INTO happyturtle (time, ad1) VALUES ('00987','www.hats.com')";
//mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
if (!$query)
   {
   die(mysql_error());
   }
 //mysql_close($con);


}

for ( $countforme = 0; $countforme <= 15; $countforme++) {

//$rightnow = $right[$countforme];


$query = "INSERT INTO happyturtle (time, ad1) VALUES ('00987','www.hats.com')";
//mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
if (!$query)
   {
   die(mysql_error());
   }
 //mysql_close($con);

}

mysql_close($con);


echo '$FileNameSQL';


fclose($FileHandle);
}
curl_close($ch);

}



?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

A quick browse showed multiple copies of:

```
 mysql_close($con);
```

So on that line, it's already closed.

You close it right after opening it:

```
$con=mysql_connect(.............
mysql_select_db($dbname ,$con);
if (!$con)
{
  die(mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($con);
```

And then try closing it again later.

Answer (score 1):

You open the connection, and then immediately close it:

```
if (!$con)
{
die(mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Later, you attempt to perform a query, but your connection has already been closed.  If you intended to place the above `mysql_close()` inside the `if` block along with `die()`, it is unnecessary there. It should be removed entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all  `mysql_close($con);` except the last one .